# Magento 2 Install schema

Tags: magento2.2, install-script

When I am adding column of `TYPE_DECIMAL` like this

```
->addColumn(
    'credit',
    Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
    null,
    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0.00', 'length' => '10,2'],
    'Decimal'
)
```

Not giving decimal length in 10,2 it makes 10,0 Why? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define the length passing as third parameter.

```
->addColumn(
    'credit',
    Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
    '10,2',
    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => '0.00'],
    'Decimal'
)
```